# Gerrit changes don't appear in IntelliJ IDEA if "List all Gerrit changes" wasn't enabled

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, gerrit

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 with Gerrit plugin installed. After cloned my project from Gerrit (it has several review-changes from my colleges already). I want to see those changes in my Gerrit plugin.

If I check the option "List all Gerrit changes" like in the image below, I can see all changes, both from my project and other projects as well.
[image]

But if I want to see only the changes in MY PROJECT, I uncheck the checkbox "List all Gerrit changes", then when I switch to Gerrit plugin panel, I see nothing, There are no change(s) there.

I had did some researching, I found one about add my project (directory/Git) to IntelliJ Version Control -> Invalidate and Restart, but nothing betters.

Is this a bug (or mis-configuration)? Is there any solution?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all 3 items from the following list are true: https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin#list-of-changes-is-empty

If this does not work you could report the issue to the plugin author: https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin/issues

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the same issue as you using `Intellij IDEA 2021.2.2` & `Gerrit` as plugin. I've installed without any problem `Gerrit` plugin and configured using own credentials. When I click on test button:

[image]

I have always `Success` as result, but my `Gerrit` board was empty as yours:

[image]

Also I tried to `tick`/`untick` the option "List all Gerrit changes (instead of changes from currently open project only)" and, yes, it works, but I wanted to check just for the project.

After some investigation, I've found the cause and it happens for me if I use `http` protocol for cloning. If I clone the project using `ssh` as protocol, I have a filled board.

So I'd recommend to check the way how you clone the project before doing any configurations.